# Total Commander Alternatives

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager

I know this is an old topic, but I still have a problem to find a good alternative, maybe I have high standards.

There is a 4 years old [article](http://168hours.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/10-total-commander-alternatives-for-linux/) about this.

But the question is, why is Nautilus so bad in two pane mode? Why is it so slow when browsing folders?
And, why are all other file managers from [article](http://168hours.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/10-total-commander-alternatives-for-linux/) so ugly?

I like Krusader, but it does not looks near as good as Nautilus.

Is Nautilus slow because of the fancy GUI rendering?
Is it hard to make file manager which fits nice in Unity?

What is your experience and what file manager are you using?

**EDIT:**

I got interesting results by making [Krusader look native in Unity](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/make-kde-applications-look-native-in.html). I like it now.

[image]

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. Please have a look at the _[What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)_ section of the [faq].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any alternatives to Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28556/are-there-any-alternatives-to-nautilus)

Comment: @Takkat We are not looking for alternatives to Nautilus, but to Total Commander, so it can't be duplicate of "Are there any alternatives to Nautilus?"

Answer (score 6):

Well, honestly I like to put here a great answer to you, but I cannot. Still I can't find an equal program to Total Commander on ubuntu. I'm thinking same way like you about on nautilus and krusader.

Additionally I had needed a good FTP client like on Total Commander.

So I have ended with 2 programs.

1. Double Commander http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/

   - (+) similar interface
   - (+) easy to use
   - (-) horrible ftp client
2. BS Commander http://www.beesoft.org/index.php?id=bsc

   - (+) similar interface
   - (-) low functionality and configuration

P.S : Even I'm thinking about starting a open source project for making something total commander.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like Double Commander, too bad there is no Ubuntu package. If you start your open source project, pay attention on performances, Unity integration, .svg non blur icon and nice two pane browsing experience. Good luck.

Comment: If you are starting a open source file manager, maybe you can fork Thunar and just make it work with two panes. I think it would be perfect.

Comment: DOUBLE COMMANDER has ubuntu package, 'sudo apt-get add-apt-repository ppa:alexx2000/doublecmd'

Answer (score 1):

All other file managers in the [article](http://168hours.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/10-total-commander-alternatives-for-linux/) are ugly, because as you have pointed out that article is dated four years back. So most of the tools in that article are bound to look outdated(Its from that time period).
For good(new age) alternatives to Nautilus, please refer this post:
[Are there any alternatives to Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28556/are-there-any-alternatives-to-nautilus)
Another list of alternatives, with screenshots:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/daily-5-5-alternative-file-managers

Personally I like the Kde default file manager `Dolphin`, after `Nautilus`.

Comment: Thanks, I liked Thunar and PCMan, but they are both missing two pane experience we have in Total Commander, Krusader and others.

Comment: @umpirsky, You could upvote this answer if it helped you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like the midnight commander. It's a terminal program but quite capable.
It's true terminal style! Terminal is never ugly.